# Try with Resource Java 7

Tags: java, java-7

I have a simple java program to test Try with resource in java , I am getting the File Not Found error, The Program and file are in the same package, Can somebody tell me what directory does File with resource start to search with

```
public class LoadConfigFile {

    public static String getProperty(String propertyName) {
        String propertyValue = null;
        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream("Properties.properties")) {
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(in);

            propertyValue = prop.getProperty(propertyName);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("Error Reading Property File" + e.getMessage().toString());
        }
        return propertyValue;
    }

}
```

Properties.properties

```
properties.one=1
properties.two=2
properties.three=3
properties.four=4
properties.five=5
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = LoadConfigFile.getProperty("property.one");

        System.out.println(s);

    }

}
```

Comment: It's possible you're not working in the directory you think you are. This line should help you figure it out: System.out.println("Active file location is: "+new File().getAbsolutePath()); . Just add that somewhere it'll get called and you should have a better idea of what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

[Working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) for process, to get that in Java you can use

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have file within a Java package you should not access it as file but as resource:

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("Properties.properties");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code for the [FileInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) constructor, you'll see that it, in turn, invokes [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)'s constructor.

And if you have a look at the documentation for [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html), you will find a good explanation of how the path string is interpreted.

In particular, notice the following snippet:

> A pathname, whether abstract or in string form, may be either absolute
>   or relative. An absolute pathname is complete in that no other
>   information is required in order to locate the file that it denotes. A
>   relative pathname, in contrast, must be interpreted in terms of
>   information taken from some other pathname. ***By default the classes in
>   the `java.io` package always resolve relative pathnames against the
>   current user directory. This directory is named by the system property
>   `user.dir`, and is typically the directory in which the Java virtual
>   machine was invoked.***